# "As powerful as just, as beneficient as wise..." Is there a literary device for this phrasing?

Tags: literary-techniques, literary-device

In a letter from Lewis and Clark to the Oto Indians, I read:

> Know that this great chief, as powerful as he is just, and as beneficent as he is wise, always entertaining a Sincere and friendly disposition towards the red people of America, has commanded us his war cheifs to undertake this long journey...

<sup>From *Letters to a Nation: A Collection of Extraordinary American Letters* by Andrew Carroll</sup>

Is there a name for the structure "*as x as he is y*" that is used in consecutive sentences and describes a common person or thing?

Comment: "Site" ("place") not "sight" ("vision").

Comment: Would this "device" include usages such as [*It's as broad as it is long*](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/It's%20as%20broad%20as%20it%20is%20long)?

Comment: @medica Thanks for your help, the post looks much better now compared to the mess I did.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - No. Your usage is purely descriptive; the OP's question centres on a rhetorical device / figure of speech. Specifically, I believe that here we have an example of the use of *simile*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes

Comment: @Featherweight - Given your reply to FumbleFingers, I suggest you modify your question to incorporate the point he raises. This is because (as I stated in my comment) the way the construction is used in FumbleFingers's comment is fundamentally different to how you used it. We have two quite different usages that appear to share the same outward form. In effect, you are asking two separate questions.

Comment: @ErikKowal I was unsure if FumbleFingers' example fit, but now I see that it doesn't. I was thinking that the literary device I am looking for, if it is not a simile, would be like an anaphora; used in consecutive sentences.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've rethought the use of the "device" and concluded that your example would not be included.

Comment: I don't know the term you're looking for, but I can't help noting that this description could be equally true if the chief is weak and unjust, or a malicious fool...

Comment: @Erik: I'd hardly say *"It's as broad as it is long"* is "purely descriptive". It's effectively an ***idiomatic usage***, similar to *"It's six of one and half-a-dozen of the other"*, both of which would probably be quite perplexing to a non-native speaker on first encounter. Whereas saying a king is *as wise as he is powerful* is a simple statement of fact that should be easily understood by anyone with even a minimal grasp of English.

Comment: You might consider [**synathroesmus:**](http://www.yourdictionary.com/synathroesmus) *- (rhetoric) Piling up of terms, especially adjectives, often as invective.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers - If I say "That table is as broad as it is long" (meaning 'it is square'), that's a purely descriptive usage, not an idiomatic one. I've also never encountered the expression in the sense of "It's six of one and half-a-dozen of the other" -- another reason I don't consider it to be an idiom. It is an established *collocation*, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: @Erik: Looking through the first few pages of results for ["it's as broad as it is long"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%27s+as+broad+as+it+is+long%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) in Google Books, I don't see a single one for the "literal" sense. Among others, [usingenglish](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/its+as+broad+as+it+is+long.html) specifically calls it an ***idiom***. But I notice they (and [some others](http://www.finedictionary.com/Longe.html)) say it's a ***British*** usage, which may be why we have different perspectives here.

Answer (score 3):

"As" establishes **simile**, the repetition **parallelism**.

> **Parallelism**: From the Greek for "beside one another," the grammatical or rhetorical framing of words, phrases, sentences, or
>   paragraphs to give structural similarity (Source: [Stanford](http://ai.stanford.edu/~csewell/culture/litterms.htm))
>
> **Simile**: An explicit comparison (using like or as): "Her lips are
>   like roses." (Source: [Cal Poly](http://cla.calpoly.edu/~dschwart/engl331/figurative.html))

Answer (score 1):

Two rhetorical terms seem relevant to this phrasing. One is *epanaphora*, which Wikipedia's [Glossary of Rhetorical Terms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_rhetorical_terms) defines as follows:

> **Epanaphora.** In rhetoric, repeating the same word or phrase at the beginning of successive phrases for emphasis. For example (from *Rhetorica ad Herennium*), "'To you must go the credit for this, to you are thanks due, to you will this act of yours bring glory.'"

The other is *enumeratio*, which the same source defines as follows:

> ***Enumeratio.*** Making a point more forcibly by listing detailed causes or effects; to enumerate: count off or list one by one.

A linked series of comparisons along the lines of "as powerful as he is just, as beneficent as he is wise" emphasizes the equivalent dignity or merit of the various items linked by *as* (*epanaphora*), and it enlarges the cited the array of virtues and powers that the thing or person so described possesses (*enumeratio*).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the known literary device is precisely as used here with the conjunction "as": "as x, as he is y…"  The phrasing can be also used in a negative way: "as greedy as he is deceitful," or "as vindictive as he is cowardly…"

You might find it helpful to read about correlative conjunctions here: http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/conjunctions.htm

"neither… nor…" and "both… and…" can be used to similar effect:  "he is neither brave nor honest"  or "he is both vigilant and aggressive" are examples I just made up. There are endless possibilities for enhancing both compliments and insults using successive clauses.

I'm not quite sure I understand the rest of the question.  If you mean duplicating the effect of this contrast on a larger scale, that is over paragraphs, rather than in a single sentence, that is certainly done often.  In fact, many short stories and novels accumulate through a succession of descriptive sketches that either reinforce one another or create unexpected surprises of contrast.  I can't think of a word for this particular style of writing.  I'm sure one can be found!